# How to use variables initialized in one method into another method in another class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to java and hence I need to know that how can I use a variable which I have initialised in one method, into another method. So I have a variable driver which is initialised in method a and I want to use it in method b, how can I do it or can I do it in the first place?

```
class Selenium{

 WebDriver driver;

   public void a(){
       driver = new FirefoxDriver();

     }

   public void b(){
       driver.get(url);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
     }
}
```

Comment: You did it! Not in a good way but you already did it.

Comment: Have a look at constructor. https://www.javatpoint.com/constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current context, all you need to do is make sure the method `a` is being called in the method `b` before making use of the `driver` object.

```
public void b(){
    a(); // makes sure the 'driver' in the class is not null for the next statement
    driver.get(url);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
}
```

In case there are fields which are local to a method and you need to provide its value to another method, you shall make use of [arguments.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)